# How would this Post Scripts commands from a PDF Stream paint?

Tags: pdf

I have this PostScript code from [this PDF's](https://www.bm-cat.ro/files/resources/721cat-cp74b.pdf) first page:

```
0 804 624 -654 re
W* n
0 792 612 -792 re
0 792 m
W n
0 792.06 612 -792 re
W n
```

I'm trying to think why would a rectangle have negative height and how would that affect the painting of the path. I know `W*` and `W` is for clipping and `n` is just a `no-op` but I don't get why would you paint a negative height rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not PostScript, its PDF, the two are different. I've removed the PostScript tag.

The content you've posted here will not paint anything at all, since (as you note) it consists entirely of clip operations applied to rectangular paths.

Most probably the path is required to be constructed that way in order to get the winding correct (this is especially important since one of the clips uses the even-odd rule)

To put it more simply, the operands to the first re are :

```
0 804 624 -654 re
```

That could be constructed from paths as:

```
0 804 m
624 804 l
624 150 l
0 150 l
h
```

The code could have used :

```
0 150 624 654 re
```

But then the equivalent path would be:

```
0 150 m
624 150 l
624 804 l
9 804 l
h
```

If you draw those rectangles (including the direction of travel) you'll see that one proceeds clockwise, while the other proceeds anti-clockwise.